# how to sum all elements a where elements b are equal

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following ArrayList:

```
a1 b1  
a2 b2  
...  
an bn
```

And I want to sum all elements **a** where elements **b** are equal. Could you please advise me the best way how it can be done?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Please show proper initialising code for the list.  And what do you mean " where b is the same"?

Answer (score 1):

Keep a map with the 'b' value as the key and add the 'a' value for that key as you iterate over the list.

Answer (score 1):

let us suppose a contains a1,a2.... a ={a1,a2,a3}
and b has b1,b2,b3...... b ={b1,b2,b3}

I had converted arraylist to arrays as follows

```
int [] a = list_a.toArray(new int[list_a.size()]);
int [] b = list_b.toArray(new int[list_b.size()]);

    int sum = 0;
    for(int r=0;r<a.length;r++)
    {
     if(a[r] == b[r])
      {
        sum = sum+a[r];

      }
```

Hope my help works